# Convergnence of subsequence of $\sup |X_n$| imply convergence of the real sequence |$X_n$|

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

I'm struggling in understanding why, if I know that a subsequence of $$\sup_n|X_n|\to0  \ \  a.s.$$ then also $$|X_n| \to 0 \ \ a.s$$
Could someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by a subsequence of $sup_n |X_n|$?

Comment: @KaboMurphy I guess $ \sup_k |X_n_k|. I'm sorry for not being so clear but is something that my professor said, but I didn't really understand what he meant, that is what I was trying to get

Comment: Let $M_n = \sup_n |X_n|$, then $M_{n_k}\to 0$ a.s. for some subsequence $\{n_k\}$. In other words, there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that
$$
\mathbb P \left(\liminf_{k\to\infty} \{|M_{n_k}(\omega)-M(\omega)|<\varepsilon\}\right)=1,\quad \forall\varepsilon>0,
$$
where $M = \lim_{n\to\infty} M_n$. 

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @OP, that cannot be right; you could just pick the even integers as your $n_k$ and have a deterministic sequence that fluctuates between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Math1000 your answer has worst my idea. I explained my doubt in this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409752/is-possible-take-a-subsequence-of-sup-nx-n . Give a look if u are glad to do it

Comment: @Alias__ I am sorry, I cannot follow your question. Perhaps English is not your first language? My apologies.